# POST dynamically added form fields?

Tags: php, sql, forms

How can I add dynamically added form fields to a POST?  This is the code I have so far, and the first field is the only one added to the POST.

Form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="index.php" method="post">
    <td>
    <input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" data-type="ID" name="idNo[]" id="idNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" data-type="model" name="model[]" id="model_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" data-type="description" name="description[]" id="description_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
    </td>   
    <td>
    <input type="text" data-type="cost" name="cost[]" id="cost_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" data-type="retail" name="retail[]" id="retail_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
```

Form dynamically add/delete :

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button" id="Add">+ Add More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and....

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="ID" name="idNo[]" id="idNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="model" name="model[]" id="model_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="description" name="description[]" id="description_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="cost" name="cost[]" id="cost_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="retail" name="retail[]" id="retail_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="quantity" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

close on form(at end of page) :

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
  <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
</div>
```

I have not started with the php needed to save the POST data to my sql database yet, am still working on getting the POST results correct.

Comment: "dynamically" added fields are still part of the dom. if you've inserted the new fields into the proper place in the dom (e.g. as children of the `<form>`), then they'll get submitted along with the rest of the form.

Comment: how do you make them "children" of the original form?

Comment: Where is the `<tr>` tag in the HTML at the top? You can't have `<td>` directly under `<form>`, you need `<table>` and `<tr>`.

Comment: your form html is invalid. you can't start a form in the middle of a table as it looks like you are. it should be `<form><table><tr><td>`, not the `<table><tr><form><td>` you have. but otherwise, what you've got is exactly what's needed. generate a new row of form stuff for you table, then append that new row to the table.

Comment: Your table should be completely inside the `<form>` tag. It seems to be the case that your table begins before the form begins. If the table is completely inside the form and you append something to it then your fields are children of the form.

Comment: you every have a "if it was a snake" moment?  thanks everyone :P, BTW how do I close my answered question if it is answered in the comments?